# Convert text to string array with separator

Tags: c#

I want to convert an string to string[] separate with ','.

```
string text = "1,2,5,6";
string[] textarray =?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string text = "1,2,5,6";
string[] textarray = text.split(',');
```

Comment: I use That And It's Worked

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
string text = "1,2,5,6";
string[] text_array =text.Split(new []{','});
```

To remove empty entries use:

```
string[] text_array =text.Split(new []{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array=text.split(",");
```

it's simple enough.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code.

```
string[] textArr = text.Split(",");
```

Comment: Any specific reason for -1 ?